# Twitter API working in console in PhpStorm but "code": 215, "message": "Bad Authentication data." in browser (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, symfony, phpstorm, browserify

I've got this code, which works swimmingly in PhpStorm console, but when I try and output it to browser, using Browserify, I get "code": 215,
"message": "Bad Authentication data." I have tested Browserify with a simple button alert event and it works just fine. I have also tried to run the code in Firefox and I get this message:

code 32 message "Could not authenticate you."

This is being done in the Symfony3 framework.

Any ideas what could be the cause of this?

```
var config = require('../../config');
var Twit = require('twit');

var T = new Twit(config);

var params = {
q: '#tbt',
count: 10
};

T.get('search/tweets', params, gotData);

function gotData(data) {
var tweets = data.statuses;
for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
    console.log(tweets[i].text);
}
}
```

Here's my config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
consumer_key:         'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
consumer_secret:      'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
access_token:         'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
access_token_secret:  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
timeout_ms:           60*1000  // optional HTTP request timeout to 
apply to all requests.
};
```

Comment: If twitter says auth details are wrong - they are (most likely) wrong.

Comment: Why does it work in PhpStorm console and not in Browser? I get the data I need with that exact code, it just doesn't work in the browser bro.

Comment: I would suggest you add more logging and if possible intercept the actual request to confirm that. "it works on my machine" is usually a weak argument.